# I'm Not a Javascript Expert .. How Can I Make a Jquery Carousel's Image Slide One By One?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, carousel

I almost have no experience with JAVASCRIPT, so I've searched a lot for a carousel with right & left arrows & lightbox (fancybox). & finally I found it ... but when I click left or right arrow , the all images row slide left or right. I need it to slide normally one image by one. How can I modify that, please ?

[Here is an image describe how the carousel look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfqnJ.jpg)

I already done with copying the carousel to my website, but the only issue is that the all images row slide left & right ... so when the user click left, the current four images got replaced with the next four images.

it's hard to write all needed codes here, I think the others Javascript files make effect on the final result. So, I attached all the needed files.[Website's Files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8MKg-Yw-ODlN2xXRGJMN3Z0b0E)

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you practice implementing the carousel following this instruction (be sure that you incorporate Bootstrap 4 accordingly).

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#with-controls

My experience with carousel is that you would have to nest `<div>` deep in each image to control their placement and sliding.  I had to create container per image for my carousel, so that was at least three levels deep. If you only use images alone per slide, you may be able to just use `div` containers alone.

Now, if you are using LightBox framework as well, then there are likely to be conflicting javascript functions.  My suggestion is that if you really want the carousel, to just use images alone, and then style it accordingly by CSS scripts and not use the Lightbox.  Otherwise, it is going deep in javascript and make custom adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Excuse me I'm not sure if I got you well, you mean that I've to make each single image to be inside a separated div ?, I took a look & found that the div with class "item" contains the four images & each "item" slide with all images. so I've to put each image inside div with "item" class to make them slide one by one?

Comment: No problem!  Yes.  I believe you need to separate each image into its own `<div>`  For example, take a look at my code at <https://github.com/pkshreeman/pkshreeman.github.io/blob/master/Experimental/index.html#L98>  That is beginning of the Bootstrap 3 Carousel, and if you look at the items (starting at line 111, second one at 126...) you can see that each item have four `<div>` but I have two columns  (Image and detail box) for each slide.  So, it may be possible for you to only need one div per image.  Experiment and see what happens.

Comment: I took a look at your code ... looks the same idea of sliding, but I guess it's closer to be slideshow. I've tried to do the same with my carousel & put each single image inside a separated div with item class. the result is the carousel row  was contains only one image, and when I click left or right arrow, all carousel sliding.

I think we need to modify something with JAVASCRIPT's "Commands". we need to know which part of JAVASCRIPT code tell the browser to slide all images instead one image.

Comment: Hm.  I did not download your zip file.  I am not comfortable doing that.  If you can, please upload it to Github so I can clone it and take a look.  If I can create the effect we are looking for, I can then do pull on your code, and you can see exactly what was changed.  It also is more 'friendly' for community if we use this type of 'code communications'.

Comment: I completely understand your discomfort to download it. I will deal with this Github process & back again, if I couldn't solve it by myself. I really appreciate your help so far!

Comment: Here is the website files on Github, I deleted some unnecessary files like few images & css files to reach the maximum 100 files
https://github.com/Haitham1000/newcarousel.github.io

Comment: Ok.  I have completed the review and made some adjustments to the forked repo which I have made a pull request on your [repo](https://github.com/Haitham1000/newcarousel.github.io/pull/1/files) so you can see the necessary changes.  The problem is that you put all images in each `<item>`.  
The `div` had all four images in it.  Just delete these and pick one.  Whatever is inside the `<div class='item'>` will be displayed as a single slide.

Comment: @user3047469 Have you had a chance to take a look at the pull request to see the 'answer'.  If that is what you are looking for, can you please my answer as an answer?  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Thank you for your effort. really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/rkrameshkumar71/qs6z1o4u/

se angle brackets to force linking: Have you seen https://jsfiddle.net/rkrameshkumar71/qs6z1o4u/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: I already have the carousel code & it works ... I just need to modify the movement of images. it should slide one image by one, not all images slide in each click